# Excluding prototype in rails 3?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

In rails 3, when using `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`, it includes a number of javascript files include prototype.js to the page.

I know I can use `config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery)` in application.rb to include more javascript files to the `:defaults` set. But how how to exclude files that are already in the `:default` set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy, take a look at this http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Speed-up-your-Ruby-on-Rails-application-by-only-including-the-Scriptaculous-libraries-you-need

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove prototype files to setup JQuery, you should take a look at this:

https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, under `config/application.rb`, there is

```
# JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
# config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)
```

so you can config the defaults there, by putting the ones you want.  Remember to uncomment the line too.

Comment: i know how to include them (as stated in my question), i just would like to exclude the prototype.js

Answer (score 0):

Remove those includes in the
In the app/view/layout/application.html.erb